# JQuery DataTable not working on Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor, datatables

I am trying to implement [jQuery DataTables](https://atmospherejs.com/menway/jquery-datatables) in my Meteor project, but I am always getting the following error. Can someone please tell me what I am missing / doing wrong here? Below is my Meteor app code. Thanks.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'pagesData' of undefined underscore.js:848
Error: Exception from Tracker recompute function:
Error: Can't call non-function: undefined
    at Spacebars.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?cb20740019f26bdca2faa89ba9c973f618118521:172:13)
    at Spacebars.mustacheImpl (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?cb20740019f26bdca2faa89ba9c973f618118521:106:25)
    at Object.Spacebars.mustache (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?cb20740019f26bdca2faa89ba9c973f618118521:110:39)
    at null._render (http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery-datatables.js?bf10e73db3f8b2f4afdc77c33ba3c62092556ae7:1010:22)
    at doRender (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1853:25)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1795:16
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:2029:12)
    at viewAutorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1794:18)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:288:36)
    at new Tracker.Computation (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:206:10)
```

Project.html - Client folder

```
<template name="projectslist">
  <div class="projectslist">

    <div>
        {{> DataTable dtProjects }}
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

Projectlist.js - Client folder

```
Template.projectslist.dtProjects =  function() {    
  return {
    id: "my-unique-table-id",
    columns: [
      {
        title: "Name",
        data: "name"
      }, {
        title: "Description",
        data: "description"
      }, {
        title: "Delivery Date",
        data: "deliverydate"
      }
    ],
    subscription: "dtProjects",
    query: {
      grade: "A"
    }
  };
};
```

Server.js - Server Folder

```
var ProjectsTable;
  ProjectsTable = new DataTableComponent({
    subscription: "dtProjects",
    collection: Projects
  });
  ProjectsTable.publish();
```

Projects.js - Available for both Server and Client:

```
Projects = new Mongo.Collection('projects');
```

Comment: Spacebars? What version of meteor is this?

Comment: @ElectricJesus Meteor 0.9.3.1

Comment: how are you adding this package? via `mrt` or `meteor add`?

Comment: @ElectricJesus As per package documentation at https://github.com/LumaPictures/meteor-jquery-datatables I am using mrt add jquery-datatables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [meteor-talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/VDwrRReQ71w), JQuery dataTables duplicates a lot of the sorting and DOM manipulation functions that MiniMongo, Spark, and Spacebars provide. So even if you can get the styling sorted out (or decided to ignore styling), sorting and other functions wind up not behaving like one is expecting when the table reactively updates underneath DataTables.

Having said so, on July 30, 2014 Austin Rivas, the creator of the meteor-jquery-datatables (which menway - creator of the [menway:jquery-datatables](https://atmospherejs.com/menway/jquery-datatables) package forked to create the Meteor Datatable package) mentioned in Meteor Google support groups:

> There are lots of difficulties with using jquery-datatables and meteor together do to duplicate functionality and having to reconcile jquery-datatables dom state with meteor reactivity.

So it might be a good idea to check another package or possibly check alternative approaches for pagination: https://github.com/awatson1978/clinical-ui-crud-table

Personally I would recommend Reactive Table https://github.com/ecohealthalliance/reactive-table. It is quite stable, easy to implement / configure.

See also:

- https://github.com/ephemer/meteor-reactive-datatables
- https://atmospherejs.com/menway/jquery-datatables
- http://reactive-table.meteor.com/

Comment: Reactive table worked! It is really bad that there is no solution for JQuery Datatables...anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the `mrt` version:

   `mrt remove jquery-datatables`
2. Add the `Meteor 0.9+` version:

   `meteor add menway:jquery-datatables`

However, it seems like it is still not 0.9 compatible as package.js still uses spacebars. Give it a shot, though.

Maybe it's worth looking at this extension instead: https://atmospherejs.com/ephemer/reactive-datatables

Comment: Just tried meteor add and got errors:  Updating package catalog                Got error during resolve; trying refresh { [Error: unknown package: jquery-datatables] constraintSolverError: true }
Could not resolve the specified constraints for this project:
Error: unknown package: jquery-datatables

Comment: On a minor note, I have updated my Meteor version (before running mrt remove / meteor add for Jquery datatables) and now using Meteor 0.9.4 (latest stable release)

Comment: Actually now I can't even run meteor update as I am always getting tons of error messages after running meteor add menway:jquery-datatables, for example: Got error during resolve; trying refresh { [Error: unknown package  jquery-datatables] constraintSolverError: true }....this is really frustrating package

Comment: don't forget the `menway:` part.. `meteor add menway:jquery-datatables`

Comment: Maybe it's worth looking at this extension instead: https://atmospherejs.com/ephemer/reactive-datatables