# Meteor, Laravel RESTful API + AngularJS or Laravel for my next web app

Tags: angularjs, rest, laravel, meteor, restful-architecture

I have a PHP background and I have build several web apps with Laravel (3 and 4). I have also experience of using RESTful APIs in my projects.

My current client have an ERP which is bunch of PHP files. Those files contains about 60K lines of spaghetti code. Client doesn't want to invest more money for developing that system so we decided to rewrite the whole app. I know all the risks about rewrite and I have also read Joel's article (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html) so there is no need for refactor or rewrite discussion.

For the new app I have been thinking to build RESTful API with Laravel (4 or 5) and frontend with AngularJS. That was before I tested Meteor 1.0. It is very promising and it would be very nice to use it for this project. But is it suitable for this kind of product?

My client's product is something like this:

- No public registration for this app (admin creates all the users)
- Complex user permissions (group level permissions and user level permissions, 6 groups)
- File handling (images, pdf etc.). Files are used as message attachments.
- Big data tables
- External API calls

App contains sections like: users, orders, offers, time tracking, sales, reporting, calendars, clients.

So is it wise to use Meteor for this kind project or do you prefer RESTful API + AngularJS combo? I'm hesitating because I'm afraid that in big projects using Meteor the code will becode mess.

Comment: "Client doesn't want to invest more money for developing that system so we decided to rewrite the whole app." - +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm working on a feasibility analysis for using meteor on a [similar project](http://github.com/reciprocity/ggrc-core) at Google, and I think Meteor would be great for your project.

- Admin user creation - check [Houston](https://atmospherejs.com/houston/admin)
- REST API - [you don't need one *for your own tools*]( need to think in Meteor terms. ). Meteor has a much simpler mechanism - [Meteor.call and Meteor.methods](https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/methods).
- User permissions - see the [roles](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles) package
- File handling - see [CollectionFS](http://collectionfs.github.io/Meteor-CollectionFS/) or search Atmosphere for [upload](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=upload).
- External API calls - HTTP.get makes it trivial. See also Atmosphere for specific packages.
- Big data tables - see this answer about [table widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26629532/1269037)

Comment: Nice list! In a future I want to make an iPhone (or android) app that sends camera photos to this system. It should be possible with PhoneGap but is that support easy to add later?

Comment: @anttir: Quite easy - see more at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration

Comment: I have been learning Meteor for one week now, and I really like it. All the beginners should read this book: https://www.discovermeteor.com/

Comment: I have to add to the answer that you can also use AngularJS on top of Meteor with this package: http://angularjs.meteor.com/

Comment: @DanDascalescu that's a very firm phrase decided after reading a very short article?   There are a lot of reasons why a lot of experienced AngularJS developers won't agree with you.  but i'm not saying it is better then Blaze, just different.  maybe reading this as well might be interesting for you: http://angularjs.meteor.com/manifest

Comment: @DanDascalescu One year after this post and more experience with meteor, you still recommend the meteor for large projects, such as an ecommerce for example?

Comment: @Liko: a modern web app with decent UX will require significant JavaScript on the client side. For the server side, unless you a have highly valuable code base or expertise in another language, it's best to choose JavaScript as well, for isomorphism, code reuse, and to minimize context switching costs. Unless you want to live on the bleeding edge, the [choice is now between the MEAN stack and Meteor](http://wiki.dandascalescu.com/essays/meteor_js_vs_the_mean_stack).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about Meteor, but for the Angular variant you can take a look at this POC application using a AngularJS client and a REST Server:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/Q3GrhAH39AU
http://www.civilian-framework.org/doc-samples.html#crm

Comment: [Angular is now officially supported by Meteor](http://info.meteor.com/blog/announcing-meteor-1.2).